# Registering onSelectionChange

Tags: excel, vue.js, office-js, office-addins

I've been trying for the last couple of days to make a taskpane add-in for excel which is based on VUE.

I've followed the guide at [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/quickstarts/excel-quickstart-vue) and i have attempted to register an event handler for onSelectionChange. It has been somewhat successful but it seems like it queues the events after some time. I then have to hover the taskpane or do something like ctrl+c for it to execute the queued up code.

I am a rookie with both JS and Vue so it's highly likely i am missing an important piece of context.

my code is as follows:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App'

Vue.config.productionTip = false

/* eslint-disable no-new */

const Office = window.Office
Office.onReady()
  .then(
    registerSelectionChange(), // moved in here based on input from Rick
    new Vue({
      el: '#app',
      components: {App},
      template: '<App></App>'
    })
  )

async function registerSelectionChange() {
  return await Excel.run(async function (context) {
      let ws = context.workbook.worksheets.getActiveWorksheet();
      ws.onSelectionChanged.add(handleSelectionChange);
      return await context.sync()
  })
}

async function handleSelectionChange(event){
    return await Excel.run(async function(context){
        let ws = context.workbook.worksheets.getActiveWorksheet();
        let range = ws.getRange(event.address)
        range.values = [[1]]
        return await context.sync()
    })
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have now discovered that there are problems with the `registerSelectionChange()`. The fix is to add `<script> MutationObserver=null; </script>` in the  section. 
More information [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/excel/excel-add-ins-events).

Answer (score 0):

Since `registerSelectionChange()` calls Office APIs, you should call it inside `Office.onReady`. See [Initializing your add-in](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/understanding-the-javascript-api-for-office#initializing-your-add-in) for details. Please see if that helps.

Comment: Hi Rick thanks for your input. I've moved it into my `.then()` and when the taskpane reloads it works. However, the problem with it queueing the events after some time still persists.

Comment: Can you provide more detail about what you mean by queuing up? What steps lead to the problem and what do you expect to see? Are you selecting different content repeatedly?

Comment: When i reload the task pane and click around the worksheet it will change the values of the selected cells to 1 for about 10 seconds. After the initial 10 seconds it will stop inputting the 1's. If i then hover the task pane or e.g. Press ctrl+c it will input 1's in all the cells which have been selected after it stopped reacting.